# Specifying which CSS file goes with a HTML template

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

The project I'm currently working on has 4-5 HTML template files, all of which use the same CSS file. I would like to change the CSS visual layout of one of the HTML files (let's call it engagement.html), and I figured that the easiest way to change that would be to create a new CSS file and have engagement.html refer that that new CSS file rather than the old CSS file .

HTML:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Title Goes Here</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/selma/selma-template-new.css' %}">

  {% include "about/_header.html" %}

</head>
<body>

  {% include "about/_topnav.html" %}

<div class=“colorChange”>Text that is supposed to change color</div>
```

New CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: Metropolis, sans-serif;
  color: red;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

My new HTML page currently looks like this. I tried to change
something simple, like the color of a paragraph. However, when I go to the browser and Chrome Developer tools, it looks like it's still getting its styles from the old-css.css file (the new paragraph color is crossed out). I've tried CTRL+SHIFT+R to refresh the cache and reloading everything, but no luck. Screenshots of developer tools show that the new CSS is linked but being overridden.

Unfortunately I did not create this code, I am merely modifying it. Is there a way for the HTML page to refer to ONLY the new CSS file somehow? I am confused why it is still referring to the old CSS file. I tried hard reloading and clearing the cache so I don't think it's a cache issue, and the template doesn't build from any previous template so it can't be that either.

[Body of old that is not being overwritten](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGzU5.png)

[New CSS being overwritten](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7Isr.png)

Comment: can you include css code here

Comment: and also full template

Comment: Make sure that the file <new-css.css> is exist in  <CSS> the folder.

Comment: Just did so! The file exists but it's just being overridden somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to double check that `{% include "about/_header.html" %}` doesn't include the old-css.css file you *don't* want loading.

Conversely, if it's just a few lines of css to override, you could make use of the `!important` flag on the css that needs to override.

Override css (selma-template-new.css):

```
body {
  color: red !important;
}
```

^ just include the lines that need to be overridden.

Comment: Thank you! Turns out header.html indeed had the old CSS file, didn't realize it could possibly be in there